# Find neighbours outside of 2d grid which is reduced into a 1d array

Tags: arrays, 2d, dimension-reduction

I have a two dimensional grid where width and height are always the same.

```
[0][1][2]
[3][4][5]
[6][7][8]
```

I reduced it's data source into a one-dimensional array.

```
[0][1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8]
```

Access of elements works, but here comes the tricky part: How to know, whether a neighbour of a cell is outside the grid when still processing the one-dimensional array?

For example the upper right neighbour of [5] is out of the grid but using a calculcated offset index, I will get [3].

Anyone with experience in this field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well assuming you know (i) the indices of the cell and (2) the dimensions of the grid (sensible right?), and that its index in the 1D array is `k`, and in the 2D array `i, j`.

Then `k = i * width + j`. Thus `i = k / width`, `j = k % width`. (`/` is integer division, `%` is modulus).

Once you get these two indices, you know the neighboring cell's indices, and you can check those against the boundaries as normal (I assume you know how).

Comment: Thank you, took me a little to implement it correctly but it is working fine!